# How to import model from one app to another?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

**The issue I face**:

```
 Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CVBuilderApp.cvs'
```

**What I did**: In my main app views file i.e, in the `CVBuilderApp.views` file
views.py:
 `from CVBuilderApp.cvs.models import PersonalInfo`

**My project structure**:

```
CVBuilderApp
- accounts
  - models, urls, views
- cvs
  - models, urls, views
- CVBuilderApp
  - settings.py
- manage.py
```

How do I import the model while the main application name and the project name are the same? Please help

Answer (score 1):

`from csv.models import PersonalInfo`

Imports are relative.
You can calling `python manage.py runserver` so everything is relative to `manage.py`

---

###### Example

```
CVBuilderApp (root)
- helpers (dir)
  - helperofhelper (dir)
      - doesthing.py    <- Import this

  - cvsHelper.py        <- from Here

- manage.py
```

if wanting to import *doesthing* inside of *cvsHelper*
you **would not** do `from helperofhelper.doesthing import dothing`
you **would** do `from helpers.helperofhelper.doesthing import dothing`

edit: missed the from

Comment: I tried this but I still get an error: ```ImportError: cannot import name 'Personal_info' from 'cvs.models'```

Comment: just give it the ol `from csv.models import *` -if you edit your question to include the models.py + mention the Model you're trying to import it would probably help us narrow it down

Answer (score 0):

you should not write project name in imports, so your imports must be something like this:

```
from cvs.models import PersonalInfo
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get an error: ```ImportError: cannot import name 'Personal_info' from 'cvs.models'```

Comment: @LibinThomas what's the name of class? ```Personal_info``` or ```PersonalInfo```

Comment: Yes! It is ```class PersonalInfo(models.Model)```

Comment: @LibinThomas So then why did you import ```Personal_info```?!

Comment: I have made the correction of classname but the error stays same ```ImportError: cannot import name 'PersonalInfo' from 'cvs.models'```

Comment: @LibinThomas did you create the app by using command ```python manage.py startapp <app_name>```?

Comment: Yes. I created the apps using the same command. My settings.py has these apps ```'CVBuilderApp',
    'accounts',
    'cvs',``` All I want to do is access the model of ```cvs``` from ```CVBuilderApp```

Answer (score 0):

Model location is relative to the location of manage.py file.
so you need to enter:

```
from cvs.models import PersonalInfo
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get an error: ```ImportError: cannot import name 'Personal_info' from 'cvs.models'```

Comment: @LibinThomas Are you writing Personal_info with an underscore ? You need to check the model name correctly.

Comment: @LibinThomas did you run makemigrations and migrate commands? 
If nothing works then run these commands, delete the db file and delete migrations file except the init file then run makemigrations and migrate commands again.

Comment: I deleted all the migrations and ran the migrate commands again. It seems like there was something wrong with the migrations. Also, IDE shows a warning with the import but your suggestion did work well. Thanks :)